# Picasso recycle view retrofit 2 in grid view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, retrofit2

Main class:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://192.168.0.2/littlezebra/scripts/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            login service = retrofit.create(login.class);


            Call<dashboard> call = service.dash();

            call.enqueue(new Callback<dashboard>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<dashboard> call, Response<dashboard> response) {

                  dashboard  dashboard = response.body();
                    data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(dashboard. getDashboard_info()));
                    adapter = new DataAdapter(data,context);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
```

Adapter class:

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<dashboard.Dashboard_info> android;
    private Context context;

    public DataAdapter(ArrayList<dashboard.Dashboard_info> android,Context context) {
        this.android = android;
        this.context = context;
    }


    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
     View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        viewHolder.tv_name.setText(android.get(i).getId());
        Picasso.with(context).load(android.get(i)
                .getWeek_image())
                .resize(250,200) //to resize Image
                .into(viewHolder.img_android);
        viewHolder.tv_api_level.setText(android.get(i).getWeek_name());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return android.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView tv_name;
        private ImageView img_android;
        private TextView tv_api_level;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            tv_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            img_android = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_android);
            tv_api_level = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_api_level);

        }
    }
```

Process:

> com.example.admin.myappl, PID: 5047 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Context must not be null. at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$Builder.(Picasso.java:701) at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.with(Picasso.java:662) at com.example.admin.myappl.Adapter.DataAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.java:37) at com.example.admin.myappl.Adapter.DataAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.java:18) at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6400) at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6433) at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5377) at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5640) at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5482) at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5478) at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2215) at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:556) at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1502) at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595) at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170) at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3625) at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3354) at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3886) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754) at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1189) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754) at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:131) at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42) at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1389) at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:868) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754) at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1192) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754) at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:383) at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:321) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754) at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1982) at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1826) at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1735) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754) at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:383) at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:321) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754) at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1982) at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1826) at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1735) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754) at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:383) at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:321) at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:751) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838) 08-16 17:01:40.928 5047-5047/com.example.admin.myappl E/AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2722)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2395) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1473) at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6976)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change** `adapter = new DataAdapter(data,context);` line to `adapter = new DataAdapter(data,YourActivity.this);`

then, go to the **Adapter** class,

and paste

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<dashboard.Dashboard_info> android;
    private Activity activity;

    public DataAdapter(ArrayList<dashboard.Dashboard_info> android,Activity activity) {
        this.android = android;
        this.activity = activity;
    }
```

now use picasso with

```
Picasso.with(activity).load(android.get(i)
                .getWeek_image())
                .resize(250,200) 
                .into(viewHolder.img_android);
```

Answer (score 0):

please

maybe problem is somewhere here:
Picasso.with(context).load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEIKP.jpg").into(imageView);

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you pass `null` context object to `Picasso.with()` method.

To fix that, you can do something like that in your `onBindViewHolder()` method:

```
//inside onBindViewHolder ()
Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load("url here").into(yourImageView);
```

So, as, you can see, you even don't need to pass context to your adapter in constructor.